# block all but a few ips with firewalld

Tags: command-line-interface, fedora, firewalld

On a linux  networked machine,  i would like to restrict the set of addresses on the "public" zone  (firewalld concept), that are allowed to reach it. So the end result would be no other machine can access  any port or protocol, except those explicitly allowed, sort of a mix of

```
  --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" source not  address="192.168.56.120" drop'

  --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" source not  address="192.168.56.105" drop'
```

The problem above is that  this is not a real list, it will block everything since if its one address its blocked by not being the same as the other, generating an accidental "drop all" effect,  how would i  "unblock" a specific non contiguous set? does source accept a list of addresses? i have not see anything in my look at the docs or google result so far.

---

EDIT:
I  just  created this:

```
# firewall-cmd  --zone=encrypt --list-all
encrypt (active)
  interfaces: eth1
  sources: 192.168.56.120
  services: ssh
  ports: 6000/tcp
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

But i can still reach port 6000 from  `.123`   my intention was that   if a source is not listed, it should not be able to reach any service or port

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The rich rules aren't necessary at all.

If you want to restrict a zone to a specific set of IPs, simply define those IPs as sources for the zone itself (and remove any interface definition that may be present, as they override source IPs).

You probably don't want to do this to the "public" zone, though, since that's semantically meant for public facing services to be open to the world.

Instead, try using a different zone such as "internal" for mostly trusted IP addresses to access potentially sensitive services such as sshd. (You can also create your own zones.)

Warning: don't mistake the special "trusted" zone with the normal "internal" zone. Any sources added to the "trusted" zone will be allowed through on all ports; adding services to "trusted" zone is allowed but it doesn't make any sense to do so.

```
firewall-cmd --zone=internal --add-service=ssh
firewall-cmd --zone=internal --add-source=192.168.56.105/32
firewall-cmd --zone=internal --add-source=192.168.56.120/32
firewall-cmd --zone=public --remove-service=ssh
```

The result of this will be a "internal" zone which permits access to ssh, but only from the two given IP addresses. To make it persistent, re-run each command with `--permanent` appended, or better, by using `firewall-cmd --runtime-to-permanent`.

Comment: please clarify what you mean by   "interface definition that may be present", iv tried your suggestion, please see my edit.

Comment: @mike Like I said, you need to remove `eth1` from the zone. `firewall-cmd --zone=encrypt --remove-interface=eth1`

Comment: well, the encrypt zone is  the new zone, before  eth1 was in  public, i moved it from public to encrypt, so encrypt has the  source  .120, i thought only 120 should be able to reach the port, what im i missing?

Comment: If you put the interface in the zone, then _anything_ arriving via the interface can access whatever ports and services are added to the zone, regardless of IP address. So it probably belongs in public, where it was originally.

Comment: ahh, so the  accepted sources will still be allowed in even if the interface is  placed in public,  and the  accept sources are placed in  a different trusted source?

Comment: The zone only applies to whatever is in the zone.

Comment: You can make the rules permanent with `firewall-cmd --runtime-to-permanent`.

Comment: Thanks, @Alxs. That option did not exist in firewalld at the time this post was written, so that's why it wasn't mentioned.

Comment: Is the last command (--remove-service=ssh) necessary? The prior commands will reject all ssh packets not from the added source addresses correct? The zone order is alphabetical so internal is before public.

Comment: @sfanjoy The commands are correct as written. Firewalld is a default-deny firewall (as is any firewall worth having). Traffic not explicitly allowed is blocked. And zones are not processed in alphabetical order. They match by source address or interface.

Answer (score 2):

First install and start firewalld service

```
sudo yum install -y firewalld
sudo systemctl start firewalld
```

Then open source IP addresses *192.168.56.120* and *192.168.56.121*.

Open ssh 22 for remote shell if needed and use [--permanent] flag to keep changes after system reboot.

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-service=ssh
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-source=192.168.56.120
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-source=192.168.56.121
```

Then reload firewalld service to activate new configuration

```
sudo systemctl reload firewalld
```

You can also mix incoming address and destination port using *rich rules* feature of *firewall-cmd*

Comment: Do not use `--permanent` to create firewall rules then reload later. This causes a mistake to lock you out, permanently as the name implies, and it is extremely difficult to recover from this.

Answer (score 1):

As per `firewalld.richlanguage`:

> Source
>              source [not] address="address[/mask]"

```
   With the source address the origin of a connection attempt can be limited to the source address. An address is either a single IP address, or a network IP address. The address has to match the rule family (IPv4/IPv6). Subnet mask is expressed in either
   dot-decimal (/x.x.x.x) or prefix (/x) notations for IPv4, and in prefix notation (/x) for IPv6 network addresses. It is possible to invert the sense of an address by adding not before address. All but the specified address will match then.
```

Specify a netmask for the address to allow contiguous blocks.

Other than that, you could try creating an `ipset` for a non-contiguous list of allowed IPs.

For example, in `/etc/firewalld/direct.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<direct>
   <rule ipv="ipv4" table="filter" chain="INPUT" priority="0">-m set --match-set whitelist src -j ACCEPT</rule>
</direct>
```

The actual `ipset` has to be created separately.

Comment: this would reject,  what i need is the inverse,  accept if in the set,

Answer (score 0):

You can manage easily by Rich Rule.

**First Step**

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --set-default-zone=home
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=drop --change-interface=eth0
```

**Second Step - Add Rich Rule**

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=home --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" source address="192.168.78.76/32" accept'
```

All port is accessible by 192.168.2.2 once you add rich rule and blocked every port from other source.

If you will add any port or service by below command then it will accessible by all sources.

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-service=ssh
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8080
```

If you want to open specific port for specific Ip than below command

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=home --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" port="8080/tcp" source address="192.168.78.76/32" accept'
```

Comment: sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --set-default-zone=internal

usage: see firewall-cmd man page

Can't use stand-alone options with other options.

Answer (score 0):

deny all connect

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=drop --change-interface=eth0
```

accept special connect

```
    firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=home --add-source=192.168.1.1/32
    or
    firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=drop --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" source address="192.168.1.1/32" accept'
```