# How do I get firewalld to restrict access to all except specified IP addresses?

Tags: iptables, redhat, centos7, firewalld

I would appreciate some assistance with configuring firewalld please. Here's a bit of background. All I want to do is prevent all access- except whitelisted IP addresses to a web application running on https.

I have done much googling. learnt a number of things but none has worked yet. Here's what I have done:

1. I can tell firewalld is running

   ```
   # systemctl status firewalld

   firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic     firewall daemon    Loaded: loaded
   (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; enabled)    Active: active
   (running)
   ```

also with

```
    # firewall-cmd –state
    running
```

2. I have the default zones

   ```
   # firewall-cmd --get-zones
   block dmz drop external home internal public trusted work
   ```
3. My active zones include:

   ```
   # firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
   public
   sources: 192.72.0.193 192.72.0.0/22 94.27.256.190
   ```
4. My default zone is public:

   ```
   # firewall-cmd --get-default-zone
   public
   ```
5. The details of public are:

   ```
   public (default)   
   interfaces:   
   sources: 192.72.0.193 192.72.0.0/22 94.27.256.190   
   services: http https ssh   
   ports:   
   masquerade: no   
   forward-ports:   
   icmp-blocks:   
   rich rules:
   ```

My understanding is that the configuration for public zone above will restrict only grant to requests from any of the specified IP addresses. However, when I try accessing https://www.example.com from an IP outside the listed, it allows it.

Comment: That looks right. Have you got other zones?

Comment: See this post for more options: http://serverfault.com/questions/680780/block-all-but-a-few-ips-with-firewalld

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one option is to remove the service: https from the zone

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --remove-service=https
```

and then use what is known as rich rules to specify what sources [IP addresses] may access what service [such as http and https] like so:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" source address="x.x.x.0/24" service name="https" log prefix="https" level="info" accept'
```

might need to reload though