# firewalld allow ssh only from one predefined IP host or AS number net

Tags: centos, firewalld, firewalld-zone

I am using  CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009  in minimal installation and  firewalld .

```
[root@centosmin firewalld]# uname -a
Linux centosmin 3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Nov 17 13:59:11 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

There are similar  question i.e. [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/680780/block-all-but-a-few-ips-with-firewalld)   but none of the responses there work. I would like to do that without using reach rules.

The target it to allow ssh only from one particular IP address on the internet. In order to simulate this behavior i have setup a lab with 3 machines in different vlans and setup routing between them in my internal network.

The server in this case is the

```
10.192.210.10/24
```

and two ssh clients:

```
10.192.52.50/24
10.192.57.6/24
```

Now i have created my own internet facing zone and made it default using the commands

```
//create new zone called internet
firewall-cmd  --permanent --new-zone=internet

// add the only ip address that should be able to connect to ssh
firewall-cmd --zone=internet --add-source=10.192.57.6/32

firewall-cmd --zone=internet --add-service=ssh

// here i make sure that i manually add the interface if it is not already add it and then remove it
firewall-cmd --zone=internet –add-interface=ens3
firewall-cmd --zone=internet --remove-interface=ens3


firewall-cmd --zone=internet --set-target=DROP
firewall-cmd --set-default-zone=internet

// save the current runtime to premanent rules
firewall-cmd --runtime-to-permanent

firewall-cmd --reload
```

after that my only one network interface look like

```
[root@centosmin firewalld]# firewall-cmd --list-all 
internet (active) 
 target: DROP 
 icmp-block-inversion: no 
 interfaces:  
 sources: 10.192.57.6/32 
 services: ssh 
 ports:  
 protocols:  
 masquerade: no 
 forward-ports:  
 source-ports:  
 icmp-blocks:  
 rich rules:
```

however i am still able to connect to ssh from the  10.192.52.50/32 host. What i am missing here

the ***`iptables -nvL -t filter`*** command tells me that there a multiple chains that are still accept . Should that not be set to DROP? And if so how to set it to reject all traffic except from the host
10.192.57.6/32

```
[root@centosmin firewalld]# iptables -nvL -t filter 
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes) 
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination          
 459 34244 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
   0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            
   0     0 INPUT_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            
   0     0 INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            
   0     0 INPUT_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            
   0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID 
   0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

a direct [link](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/sec-working_with_zones#sec-Using_Zone_Targets_to_Set_Default_Behavior_for_Incoming_Traffic) from RedHat tells us that in order to do that we need to set the target. But i already did that in the previous step and i am still able to connect from 10.192.52.50/32 which is not the expected behavior.

Addition adding requested output of the command

```
[root@centosmin firewalld]# firewall-cmd --list-all-zones
block
  target: %%REJECT%%
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: 
  sources: 
  services: 
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 


dmz
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: 
  sources: 
  services: ssh
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 


drop
  target: DROP
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: 
  sources: 
  services: 
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 


external
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: 
  sources: 
  services: ssh
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  masquerade: yes
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 


home
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: 
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client mdns samba-client ssh
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 


internal
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: 
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client mdns samba-client ssh
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 


internet (active)
  target: DROP
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: 
  sources: 10.192.57.6/32
  services: ssh
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 


public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: 
  sources: 10.192.57.6
  services: ssh
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 


trusted
  target: ACCEPT
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: 
  sources: 
  services: 
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 


work
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: 
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

Comment: Did you allow ssh in another zone?

Comment: in which other zone there in only one zone  called "internet"

Comment: the server has only one network interface

Comment: The `firewall-cmd --list-all` does not list all zones there are, use `firewall-cmd --list-all-zones`

Comment: @DanilaVershinin i just added the output of the requested command to the question, however i want to notice that only one zone should be used in this case.

Comment: From there you can see that `ssh` is allowed in public zone as well. You need to remove it from there, e.g. `firewall-cmd --permanent --remove-service=ssh`

Comment: OK i manage to get the desired behavior by setting all other zones to target drop, and removing all the services from the other zones. The trick part was to remove the interface from the zone itself. I do not know why we need to remove it from the "internet" zone but by removing it i saw that it is working. Nevertheless i would like to understand why we need to remove the interface from the zone.